# Cannot search in Outlook 2010

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2010, search

I recently reinstalled Windows 7 (64-bit Professional), and reinstalling Outlook 2010 was part of that process. I am now unable to search for anything in Outlook, as it simply returns that no results were found. The Windows Search service is running.

I can rebuild the search index manually (Options --> Search --> Indexing Options --> Advanced --> Rebuild), and it will work for the next time or two that I open Outlook, but it then stops working again.

Outlook is listed in the indexed files window that pops up when Indexing Options is clicked.

Comment: Have you imported your old PST files?

Comment: No, I did not import them, I just let it recreate them.

Comment: If you have the archives, import might help